# ¿Como aplicar efecto hover desde javascript a las celdas de una tabla html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

este pequeño programa contiene una tabla simple HTML el cual posee dos botones abajo para manipular la celdas.

boton 1: entra en el modo de selección, es decir, la tabla completa se pinta de un color ej:rojo y en este punto, quisiera que a través de eventos como "mouseenter" y "mouseover" se aplique un hover para que al pasar el mouse sobre cada celda se pinte de otro color ej:verde, como indicando mi selección pero no han funcionado.

boton 2: una vez seleccionada la celda con un click, este debe remover los eventos del mouse que causan el hover y tampoco han funcionado.

He logrado aplicar el hover de otra manera pero al presionar el boton secundario los eventos siguen aplicando color a las celdas. Tengo entendido que removeEventListener podría solucionar lo de remover los eventos

Les dejo mi código:

```
//metodos que añaden y sacan los efectos
function addEffect(td) {
    td.className = 'td-hover';
} 
function remEffect(td) {
    td.className = '';
}

// funcion del boton primario
function cellSelector() {
    table.style.background = 'rgba(30, 105, 204, 0.5)';
    const td = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(let i = 0, j = td.length; i < j; i++) {
        td[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', addEffect(this));                 
        td[i].addEventListener('mouseover', remEffect(this));
    }
}

                                     
// funcion del boton secundario
btn_done.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (table.style.background != null) {
        table.style.background = 'none';
    }
});
```

Soy nuevo en JS.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el archivo html y el archivo css por favor?, de todas formas, creo que esto puede ayudarte:  [hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp), si quieres un hover simplemente ponlo en el .css, no lo gestiones con JavaScript, yo con Javascript gestionaría que le meta y le quite una clase por ejemplo llamada "conEfectoHover" con `.addClass("conEfectoHover")` y `.removeClass("conEfectoHover")` y en el css le pones `.conEfectoHover:hover{lo que quieras }`

Comment: tienes razón, la próxima incrustare html y css pero ya lo he conseguido muchas gracias @chikebox

Answer (score 1):

he aquí la respuesta

se define una clase CSS

```
.td-hover:hover {
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

luego con JavaScript se habilita y deshabilita esa clase CSS

```
// función que habilita la clase CSS con el hover 
function enableCellSelector() {
    // obteniendo celdas de la tabla HTML
    const td = table.querySelectorAll('td');
    for(let i = 0, j = td.length; i < j; i++) {
        //aplicando la clase css a las celdas 
        td[i].classList.add('td-hover');
    }
}

// función que deshabilita la clase CSS con el hover
function disableCellSelector() {
    const td = table.querySelectorAll('td');
    for(let i = 0, j = td.length; i < j; i++) {
        // removiendo clase css a las celdas
        td[i].classList.remove('td-hover');
    }
}
```